# Should I make cublas handle global and reuse them in different (host) functions?

Tags: cuda, cublas

I think this saves some configuration time, but I am not sure whether this will cause unexpected behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to issue calls in any sort of thread concurrency scenario, its recommended to use independent handles:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#thread-safety2

> The library is thread safe and its functions can be called from multiple host threads, as long as threads do not share the same cuBLAS handle simultaneously.

Also note that the device associated with a particular cublas handle is expected to remain unchanged for duration of handle use:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-context

> The device associated with a particular cuBLAS context is assumed to remain unchanged between the corresponding `cublasCreate()` and `cublasDestroy()` calls.

Otherwise, using a single handle should be fine amongst cublas calls belonging to the same device and host thread, even if shared amongst multiple streams.

An example of using a single "global" handle with multiple streamed CUBLAS calls (from the same host thread, on the same GPU device) is given in the CUDA `batchCUBLAS` [sample code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#batchcublas).

Comment: Is this still correct? in https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/ it says "The library is thread safe and its functions can be called from multiple host threads, even with the same handle." What it doesn't say is if by reusing the same handle there will be a penalty (e.g. contention). If there is no penalty (and supposing one never needs to change the behavior settings) is there still a reason to use different handles in different threads?